# Pick Observable latest value when any value is produced by another Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an Observable generated from a regular .NET event. The Observable is hot - not *warm* - in the sense that it starts producing values even before any subscription, and everytime someone subscribes it will receive the latest produced value. Let's name this `eventStream`.

Then I have another Observable, exposed by another class, which represents some *state flow*, so every new value gives the current state of something managed by that class. This Observable is hot as well. Let's name it `stateStream`.

Everytime the event sequence produces a new value, I want to pick (I'd say *sample*, but that might lead to confusion) the latest value provided by state sequence. This should produce a new sequence, combining the two values, then processing them, etc.

This is what I came up with, but it does not seem to work though:

```
var eventStream = Observable.FromEventPattern<MyEventArgs>(/*...*/);
var stateStream = someDependency.SomeStateStream;

eventStream.Select(eventValue => 
  stateStream
    .Take(1)
    .Select(stateValue => new { Event = eventValue, State = stateValue }))
  .Switch()
  .Do(value => _logger.Trace("{{ {0}, {1} }}", value.Event, value.State))
  .Subscribe(value => /* do something */);
```

The rationale behind that is taken from other similar scenarios I worked with, where a new value produced by some source causes a new subscription to run, thus a **new** Observable gets returned, and finally the `IObservable<IObservable<...>>` gets squashed into a *one-dimensional* IObservable again using `Switch()` or some similar operator.
But in this case, from a quick test, there seems to be no new subscription, and  only the very first `stateStream` value gets produced. Instead I'd like to pick the first value (`Take(1)`) everytime the `eventStream` *fires*.

AFAIK, `CombineLatest` and `Zip` cannot fit the bill: `CombineLatest` fires everytime one of the two sequences provides a new value; `Zip` fires everytime both sequences have a new value available, and tipically this means when the slowest of the two has values. `And/Then/When` should not be right as well for same reason as `Zip`.

I've also checked SO thread [combining one observable with latest from another observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507484/combining-one-observable-with-latest-from-another-observable), but I don't think that can apply here. Only in one of the comments I read

> [...] and then Scan acts like a CombineLatest that filters for notifications from only one side

and somehow it sounded familiar, but I could not wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want Observable.Sample()

```
stateSource.Sample(eventSource)
     .Zip(eventSource,...)
```

Comment: I had been reading IntroToRx, and it wasn't clear to me that I could also sample based on another observable. That sounds as a good fit.

Comment: I tried with this approach and the immediate problem seemed solved: the sampling was effective. And with the closing `Zip(eventSource, ...)` I was also able to *bring on* the event value down the chian. Then I had further requirements: to process events differently based on the most recent state, plus some more. I was able to solve those following @Enigmativity approach. While I haven't actually tried to face those requirement with your approach, it looks like that would do as well.

Comment: ...and it actually does work, judging by current unit tests

Comment: well ... I guess it is just how things evolved

Comment: @superjos - Can you please confirm how you are using this answer? In my tests I don't get the sequence you asked for.

Comment: Yes. What difference do you find in your tests? In my unit tests (on the actual code, not this example), both this and yours run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your current solution is actually pretty close, but it sounds like you just need to swap the `eventStream` & `stateStream` observables around and then remove the `.Take(1)`.

Try this:

```
stateStream
    .Select(stateValue => 
        eventStream
            .Select(eventValue => new { Event = eventValue, State = stateValue }))
    .Switch()
    .Do(value => _logger.Trace("{{ {0}, {1} }}", value.Event, value.State))
    .Subscribe(value => { /* do something */ });
```

Depending on how `stateStream` is configured you may need to add a `.StartWith(...)` to it to get the initial values from `eventStream`, but I think this approach covers your requirements.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the swap? It looks like that if I select `eventStream` everytime state changes, then I might miss some `eventStream` occurences. Maybe I got that wrong.  
Re: `StartsWith()`: while `someDependency` is constructed, `stateStream` is created with a `Replay(1)` and `Connect()` and it has its own `StartsWith()`, so by the time it gets to here it is already up and running. Anyway I'm considering adding an initial value to the stream being built and subscribed here.

Comment: Uhm, actually thinking more about this approach, it could work great: it looks like one can actually change the way each event is processed, based on the most recent state ... which is actually what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a default value for the state stream, in case it hasn't ever emitted. Pass this default as the argument to `MostRecent` (I just used `null` here) and use the overload of `Zip` that expects an `IEnumerable`:

```
eventStream.Zip(
    stateStream.MostRecent(null),
    (evt,state) => new { Event = evt, State = state })
.Subscribe(/* etc */);
```

Comment: Uh! I don't think I knew about `MostRecent` (nor `Latest`), will have to look into that! Thanks

Comment: What happens here if *stateStream* produces a new value after an *eventStream* N-th value and before the next, N-th + 1? I need the output to be insensitive in this case, and just detect the new state value when the N-th+1 event value arrives. It seems to me that zipping over MostRecent would still emit as soon as state changes. I guess I must be missing something

Comment: No, the eventStream emitting is the only thing that triggers an event. Suggest you try running the code to see! This is not the normal overload of Zip.

Comment: In the end I was able to go with the other proposed approach, which seemed to fit better with my idea of how things should work. I must say that, still, this mix of enumerable with observable in order to pick up a single value sounds strange, somehow I find it harder to reason about.

Comment: I agree it looks unusual - I think the key here is realise is that the enumerable makes sense once you realise you are not really being *reactive* to that state - it's only the event stream you are being reactive with. "When the event occurs, you *pull* the most recent state value." Ultimately, the accepted solution is really exactly the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

The latest (beta) version of Rx.Net 2.3.0-beta2 has `WithLatestFrom`:

```
//Only emits when eventStream emits
eventStream.WithLatestFrom(stateStream.StartWith(defaultState), 
                           (evt, state) => new {Event = evt, State = state})
           .Subscribe(/*Do something*/);
```

If not you can fill it in a pinch by using (note untested):

```
public static IObservable<TResult> WithLatestFrom<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TLeft> source,
    IObservable<TRight> other,
    Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Publish(os =>
        other.Select(a => os
            .Select(b => resultSelector(b,a)))
            .Switch());
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/90) courtesy of @JamesWorld if I am not mistaken.